# I can't access Windows 7 dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, partitioning

I'm hoping it's not all gone.

I had a Windows Recovery partition, but I can't access that. Only Ubuntu in grub.

GParted:

[image]

Comment: Tell me if I'm right: You tried adding a 6 GB swap partition as well as a 30 GB linux partition. If that's correct, you might be kind of in luck. I'd advise booting into a live drive, and seeing if you can mount the other partitions of your hard drive (I see that it skips /dev/sda2 and 3). This isn't my specialty though, so I'm not sure how you'll save it if it is still (or isn't) there.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of GParted? (use http://imgur.com)

Comment: Musher: You are correct. You're giving me some hope. Thank you either way. Wilf: screenshot added to original post.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I somehow did wipe out the Windows install. I eventually re-partitioned and reinstalled Windows. Now running 14.04 and Win 7, with Win 10 on the way. We will see how that upgrade goes.

Answer (score 0):

**Most likely you lost it**

Most likely, you accidentally installed it over windows instead of alongside it. Another thing you could try is using the terminal and typing sudo update-grub, this will scan for operating systems on the hard drive and put it in the start-up grub. If it finds nothing, most likely you have lost it.