# Cant access Windows 7 after dual-booting with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I'm very new to Linux.

Recently I tried to dual-boot Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with Windows 7. I burned the Ubuntu ISO to a DVD and booted my PC from there. Prior to this, I shrunk my Windows C: Partition by 28 GB, leaving enough unallocated space for Ubuntu. During installation though, I did not see an "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7" option as I expected to, but rather just two options: "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" and "Something else".

Following some online instructions, I chose the "Something else" option. I created 4 partitions from apparently "free space" (although my Windows partition was located there): One for the operating system itself, another for my data, one as a swap area, and lastly a 20 MB partition for BIOS bootloader (I was unsure about this).

Ubuntu installed fine, but after restarting my computer, it booted directly into Ubuntu, without displaying the GRUB bootloader menu that I expected.

As my machine started I entered "Boot Options" only to find this had nothing to do with operating systems.

Using my Windows 7 laptop, I created a system repair disc and booted my computer from it. Strangely it displayed an error message that the disc "was not compatible with my version of Windows." This does not make sense as both my desktop and laptop are 64-bit versions of Windows 7.

I could also only access the F8 Windows Startup Repair menu when booting from the system repair disc.

I have all my files on Windows 7, and it is critical that I am able to recover this operating system. Any help at all would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/496546/i-cant-access-windows-7-dual-boot-with-12-04.

Comment: It would help to see a list of the partitions on your hard disk. You can do this in Ubuntu by launching the terminal (Ctrl - Alt + T) and entering the following command: `sudo fdisk -l`. Copy the output of this command and update your question and add this new info to it, this will help us determine if the Ubuntu installation wiped/affected your Windows partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### My Hypothesis

I'm 95% certain that you've accidentally trashed your Windows installation. Evidence:

> Following some online instructions, I chose the "Something else" option. I created 4 partitions from apparently "free space" (although my Windows partition was located there)

The "Something Else" option shows the disk and all current partitions. If it misidentified the disk as being empty when in fact there were current partitions, then you could easily trash your installation in this way. In fact, there's a known bug in libparted (upon which the Ubuntu installer's partitioner is based) that causes it to show the disk as empty when the partition table deviates from absolute perfection. The most likely explanation is that you started with a GPT disk but installed Windows in BIOS mode, which would have caused a GPT-to-MBR conversion that left some GPT data intact. This confuses libparted, resulting in the "blank disk" problem. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html) for details and a fix (which will no longer work for you -- by setting up new partitions, you're long past the point where it can be fixed).

Incidentally, I tried looking for a bug report about this [on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/) (Ubuntu's bug-tracker), but didn't find one, which is surprising. Perhaps I'll investigate further and file a bug report, since this problem is so serious.

> Ubuntu installed fine, but after restarting my computer, it booted directly into Ubuntu, without displaying the GRUB bootloader menu that I expected.

This behavior is consistent with a completely trashed Windows, although there are also other possible explanations.

> Using my Windows 7 laptop, I created a system repair disc and booted my computer from it. Strangely it displayed an error message that the disc "was not compatible with my version of Windows." This does not make sense as both my desktop and laptop are 64-bit versions of Windows 7.

This is also consistent with my hypothesis, although again, there are other explanations. Note that the "compatibility" in this quote refers (or can refer) to the partition table type -- Windows ties the [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partition table to a BIOS-mode boot and the [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) to an EFI-mode boot. If the Windows installer boots in BIOS mode and sees a GPT disk, or if it boots in EFI mode and sees an MBR disk, it will refuse to do anything with the disk, except (in some circumstances) to repartition the disk and re-install.

### Further Diagnoses

To test my hypothesis, you need to examine your partition table. You can do this with GParted, `parted`, `gdisk`, or other tools. The easiest and best for the moment is `parted`:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                 Flags
 1      524kB   1573kB  1049kB               BIOS boot partition  bios_grub
 2      1573kB  580MB   579MB   fat32        EFI System           boot
 3      580MB   1106MB  525MB   ext4         Xubuntu /boot
 4      1631MB  250GB   248GB                Linux LVM            lvm
```

The output of `parted /dev/sda print` will show your partition table. The `Partition Table:` line shows the partition table type -- GPT in this example. (MBR shows as `msdos`.) More important is the details of the partitions. If you see one or more NTFS partitions, then I'm probably wrong and Windows may be intact. If you see nothing but Linux partitions (ext4fs, Linux LVM, etc.), as in this example, then my hypothesis is correct. (Note that the FAT32 partition in my example is an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which holds boot loaders for all OSes.)

If you need help interpreting your partition table, please cut-and-paste the output of `parted` to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL to your document here.

### Fixing It

If I'm right, you can't fix the problem -- at least, not completely. The best you can do is:

1. ***STOP USING THE INSTALLED OS IMMEDIATELY!*** Every moment you use the computer from its on-disk Ubuntu is another moment in which Ubuntu may write data over the remnants of your personal files on the hard disk.
2. If you don't already have one, buy a disk to use for data recovery. An external disk big enough to hold all your personal files should do fine.
3. Boot to an emergency disk (like the Ubuntu installer in its "try before installing" mode). A good case can be made for Windows emergency tools, too.
4. Run [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or similar software. These tools enable you to recover *individual files*, even from an overwritten filesystem -- which is what you've got. I've seen claims that some Windows tools can do a better job at recovering files from an overwritten NTFS partition than PhotoRec can, but I don't have specific program names or URLs. Note that you'll need to recover files to *another physical disk* -- hence step #2. Also, you're unlikely to recover all your files, and you may spend hours sifting through the files you recover to properly organize them. You may end up with a bunch of Windows program files, which you can throw away -- it will be easier to re-install Windows and your programs than to try to use those individual program files.
5. If you want it, re-install Windows. This will require learning about EFI vs. BIOS boot modes. You may want to read [this page of mine on the subject,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) which may help you navigate this minefield. (Note that BIOS/CSM/legacy boot issues may have been part of what set you on the path to this problem, but the most important issue, if my hypothesis is correct, was the bug in libparted.)

This procedure assumes that, like most people, you lack good backups. If you've got good backups, you can restore your personal files from them with much less fuss.

---

### Update

I just did some tests, and it looks like the bug that I think bit you has been fixed in Ubuntu 15.04. I'm pretty certain it was present in 14.04.

Comment: [Partition Table](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12010346)

Thank you so much for this response!

Since Ubuntu was installed, I have not downloaded any updates, software, or files, so I hope this increases my chances of recovery.

Comment: There's no evidence of Windows on your disk, so unless it's on a second physical disk, you pretty much have to restore from a backup, do a tedious file-level recovery, or give up on any data the drive used to contain. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. No need to be sorry. I was wondering if you could recommend any file-recovery software to me. I am not sure about this, but doesn't Windows automatically make make images of the drive from time to time. If so, would these have been wiped out already? Would a Windows installation disc be of any use to me at this point?

Comment: Anything on the main disk is useless for recovery. See step #4 under "Fixing It" for a recovery software pointer.